# Re-attempt memory allocation should it fail the first time?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management

I want to write code that is somewhat resistant to running out of memory.  How I'm trying to go about it, is if any memory allocation fails, it will pause execution at that point and ask the operator if they can attempt to free some memory before re-attempting the allocation (or should it prove impossible, they can choose to terminate the program themselves, it's up to them)

My code for this so far seems pretty ugly though.  This is the block that proceeds any std::vector operation that could potentially expand the array:

```
while(pointVector.size() == pointVector.capacity){
    // will not break past this if the while statement remains true
    // ERROR.report() has the power to kill the program if it needs to
    try{
        pointVector.reserve(pointVector.capacity * 2); // edited
    }catch(...){
        ERROR.report(Error::Severity::Memory
                    , __LINE__, __FILE__
                    , "Failed to allocate enough points"
                    , pointVector.size(), 0, 0);
    }
}

pointVector.push_back(point);
```

The `ERROR` object is specially pre-allocated all of it's resources so it can ask the operator without causing any new problems (in theory).  My question is, is there a better form this can take?  Does C++ have 're-try' logic for this kind of situation?  Or is this pretty much how it should go?

Comment: Use a custom allocator for your vector, this way you can wrap the logic inside the allocator and you won't need to pollute all your code with `reserve` and `try/catch` and what not.

Comment: @delnan - Actually, it only expands it by 32 units each time.  There are a great many points, thousands for this particular vector.  The worst-case for wasted space, is only 31 points, which is not very bad I think

Comment: Unless your application has insane memory requirements (that are hard) or runs on a tiny embedded device, attempting such recovery seems like much more work than it's worth. Users should know not to use applications when they're out of memory.

Comment: Your exact application and platform will determine whether this is at all practical, but in most cases, if you're running out of memory at a certain point in the run, you're going to be running out again soon even if you free some up.

Comment: @syam - I tried to do that at one time actually, but I'm going to admit.  Writing a custom allocator has proven way above my skill level.  And there's not many others floating around that I reference.

Comment: @MarkB - The application is a game, so it's nothing life or death, though it does use a lot of memory.  It's more to let the user know why something is going awry, when, where, and create a recourse for them (even if it's futile in some cases).  At least, just suddenly quitting can cause a lot of frustration if it occurs at the wrong time.  Anything I can do to mitigate that is time well spent I think

Comment: @syam - ... that's really all there is to it?  Oh wow, thanks!  I can finally use vectors and maps without try/catch blocks clogging everything (Your comment seems to have disappeared, but thank you for the short example you linked)

Comment: @Clairvoire No, sorry, I went too fast and messed it up: `new T[n]` and `delete[] ptr` construct/destruct the objects but that doesn't match the requirements of an allocator. I don't have working code at hand that I can copy, but it involves a bit more (mostly memory alignment issues, and (de)allocating raw buffers). I'm going to try and put together something that actually works.

Comment: @Clairvoire [Here is a correct version](http://ideone.com/jLixYY) that uses C++11's `aligned_storage`. Sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: I haven't used it but you could try [`std::set_new_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler) to set a callback that begs for more memory before retrying the allocation or allowing it to fail.

Comment: @syam - Thank you for taking the time!  I'll have to look up how the alignment templates you used work, so I know what's happening, but this is a really great starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the principle of "you only pay for what you use", C++ does not "repeat" or "try again" by itself.

Whether it is actually worth trying again in such a case is this is of course another matter... Unless you have a system where you are running something system critical, and low memory operation is a big part of the situations that you are required to handle, I'd say it's probably WORSE to try again than to bail out.

You may also check if the error is something other than `std::bad_alloc` [or whatever the "you can't allocate" is called], as retrying if there is some other error is probably pretty pointless.

You should definitely set a limit for the number of times you repeat the loop (just in case there is a bug in `ERROR.report()`).

[Growing by 32 at a time is fine as long as your list of items is fairly small - but I have seen code almost identical to this cause problems, because by growing "only" 32 at a time to a total size of 32MB, it causes the data to be copied a gazillion times, making the application appear like it had hung, and thus got a bug-report from a user. Changing it to a geometric growth (double each time) fixed that particular bug].

Comment: I was thinking of changing the +32 to *2.  I suppose I should go ahead and do so.  I only added that constraint because I worried `push_back()` only expanded the array by 1 every time, which would've been pretty outrageous.

Comment: `push_back()` is (pretty much) guaranteed to grow by `2 * size()` because `vector` is guaranteed to have a average complexity to add individual elements of `O(1)` - if it grows by one at a time, the average complexity becomes `O(n)`, which is not what the C++ standard says it should do.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know!  I'm sure I can rewrite the function to account for that, perhaps skipping the first comparison and just seeing if `push_back()` threw, but for now, I'll just fix the question so the block mimics how `push_back()` would otherwise do the allocation

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no, C++ does not have a built-in way around this. Running out of memory is not something a programming language can usually accommodate, so it will fail, assuming that continued functionality is not possible without the desired memory. Since there is no intrinsic 're-try' logic, you're left with something like what you have. Sorry, there isn't a particularly clean method here.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have truly exceptional requirements you aren't discussing inyour question, it's not unreasonable for an application to simply exit if it's memory needs are not met: Let the user free up memory and run your program again. This avoids writing extra code that won't be needed in 99.9% of cases, and in this case, that can *drastically* affect your performance.

For example, normally `push_back` runs in amortized constant time, but your "grow + pushback" combination would actually run in *linear* time due to linearly increasing the size of the container. This huge performance decrease would affect all your users while providing benefit for only those tiny fraction that experience running out of memory.

Comment: The program is a game, in this case.  Not critical in the sense that it's life or death, but it'd be nice to let the user know where the problem lies before crashing, or perhaps give them a chance to correct the situation.  (Error has enough pre-allocated overhead that it can 'try' to save the game's state and reload everything if it needs to, so progress isn't lost).  edit: looks like I was wrong about push_back(), I edited the question so the block reflects how push_back() would otherwise allocate the memory

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [`std::set_new_handler(new_handler new_p)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler)

It allows you to specify a method that is called if an allocation is about to fail because your program ran out of memory. This method then has the opportunity to free some memory so the allocation can succeed. If the method is able to free some memory it should return true, otherwise it has to throw a bad_alloc exception or terminate the program. (The documentation for `set_new_handler` has more specific information.)

One nice feature of using `set_new_handler` is that you then don't have to wrap every call to new in a try/catch block to make sure you haven't run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach would instead be to allocate memory in a memory pool and use memory from there instead, that way you will have full control of the memory and can do some cleaning up like defragmentation if you run out of memory. Doing a recovery the way you propose would IMHO just delay the inevitable.